# Compress then encrypt via buffer in Java

Tags: java, encryption, compression

I'm new to encryption/compression in Java and I'm working on a test project where the goal is to compress and then encrypt files via a buffered input in Java. At no point should the file be stored on disk in a non-encrypted format, therefore I want to do the compression and encryption solely on a buffer until the file is fully written.

So the progression would be: read part of file into memory (buffer, 1024 bytes) -> compress (~32 bytes)-> encrypt -> output to disk -> repeat until entire file is written

The issue I'm facing is that once I perform the reverse operations to read the compressed/encrypted file back, only part of the data is there.

To accomplish my goal, I've been combining the Inflater/Deflater classes and a block cipher with AES 256 encryption.

Encryption setup:

```
    byte[] randomSalt = new byte[8];
    SecureRandom secRand = new SecureRandom();
    secRand.nextBytes(randomSalt);

    String randomPassword = new BigInteger(130, secRand).toString(32);

    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(randomPassword.toCharArray(), randomSalt, 65536, 256);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
    AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
    byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
```

Getting input / writing output:

```
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInput = new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream("file.txt"));

    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutput = new BufferedOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream("encrypted file"));

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    try {
        while (bufferedInput.read(buffer) != -1) {

            byte[] encryptedBuffer = cipher.doFinal(compress(buffer));

            bufferedOutput.write(encryptedBuffer);
            bufferedOutput.flush();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        //snip

    } finally {

        bufferedInput.close();
        bufferedOutput.close();

    }
```

Compress method:

```
    public static byte[] compress(byte[] data) throws IOException{

    Deflater deflater = new Deflater();

    deflater.setInput(data);

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);

    deflater.finish();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    while(!deflater.finished()){

        int count = deflater.deflate(buffer);

        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);

    }

    outputStream.close();

    return outputStream.toByteArray();

}
```

What can I do to be able to compress and encrypt a file 1KB at a time and get the file back in its entirety when I perform the reverse operations?

Comment: Why are you not using the `Crypto*Stream` classes?

Comment: @LukePark Ignorance most likely. As I said, I'm pretty new to cryptography so I don't know the best practices. I'll look into those classes. Thanks!

Comment: `doFinal()` should only be used on the final block you encrypt. Use `update()` until the last block.